# Azure search Powershell deployment issue

Tags: azure, powershell, search

We have set up for over a year automated deployment to azure to do different steps. which has been working great last week one specific step has been failing. It is setting the partition size based on a variable.
this is the PS Code:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $OctopusParameters["AzureSearch.Admin.Password"] -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($OctopusParameters["AzureSearch.Admin.User"], $secpasswd)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds
$Resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Search/searchServices" -ResourceGroupName $OctopusParameters["Azure.ResourceGroup"] -ResourceName $OctopusParameters["AzureSearch.SearchServiceName"]
$Resource.Properties.partitionCount = $OctopusParameters["AzureSearch.PartitionCount"]
$Resource | Set-AzureRmResource -Force
```

this is what the error message is now:

> - $Resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Search/searc ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DisallowedOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet

is there some changes in Azure that caused this as of last week?

Comment: I am off work today personal day. So I will get back to you when I try it out

Comment: ok, wait for you.;-)

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: No, I just disabled the step. I am working on a more important project currently.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error, but you could use this command [`Set-AzureRmSearchService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.search/set-azurermsearchservice?view=azurermps-6.8.1) to set `PartitionCount`.

**Note**: You need to install `AzureRM.Search` powershell module, run this command `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Search -AllowPrerelease` *as admin* in your powershell, more details see this [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Search/0.1.2-preview).

**Command sample:**

```
Set-AzureRmSearchService -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -Name "<AzureSearchName>" -PartitionCount 2 -ReplicaCount 2
```

**Result:**

[image]